# CSS/HTML table rendering issue, p element shows up behind td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make a basic calendar / resource manager where you can drag a P element into the calendar on a given day.

The calendar generates html dates through PHP. Just a fairly basic TABLE, TR, TD structure.

There are draggable P elements, these are job orders you can drag on any given day (TD) in the calendar.
A javascript prompt shows up and you can select the duration of this job order.
The javascript function simply changes the width of the P element to overlap the table structure horizontally according to the job duration. Simply setting style.borderRight ="none" on these TDs to make it look tidy. Also a max-width is defined so that the TD wont resize when the P is resized.

The problem is that it actually shows up behind the columns it's supposed to overlap. The only way I could fix that was having no background-color on the TD. As you can see below there is a background color on the saturdays and sundays.
The P shows up behind those. (not the text however). Why is this? I guess the problem is that it's actually just appended on one TD and tries to overlap the others, probably makes for some rendering problems.

Any quick CSS fix for this?

[Overlapping but showing up below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzAYf.png)

```
  td.slot {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 70px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: .5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c9cacc;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

p.order {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #a9c5f2;
  padding: .5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Show your html or your fiddle here

Comment: The link is of an image of a table display and not the HTML table discussed. Because of this, it provides very little information that can be used to help answer your question.